# TSQL Array Initialization and LINQ Where on Array

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, initialization, string-aggregation

I'm trying to perform string aggregation on an Address in T-SQL so that any of the Address's fields which are not NULL are used in a comma-separated string.  I know how I would do this in C# but am lost with SQL.

Here's what I have so far (I need to convert the C# part into SQL):

```
SELECT STRING_AGG
(
    --Start of C# (I don't know how to convert this into SQL).
    new[]
    {
        Addresses.Line1,
        Addresses.Line2,
        Addresses.Line3,
        Addresses.City,
        Addresses.County,
        Addresses.State,
        Countries.Name,
        Addresses.Postcode
    }
    .Where(data => data != null)
    --End of C#
    ,
    ', '
) Address
FROM Addresses
JOIN Countries ON Countries.Id = Addresses.CountryId
```

Comment: Try DBNull.Value  instead of null.

Comment: @jdweng the question here is about TSQL; the C# is purely to express intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd bring them back as columns and worrying about formatting in the application code, however!

`STRING_AGG` is really intended for concatenating *row* data; you are working with *columns*, so you're probably better off doing something more like:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(Addresses.Line1,
    N', ' + Addresses.Line2,
    N', ' + Addresses.Line3,
    -- ...
    N', ' + Addresses.Postcode)
```

`CONCAT` ignores `null` values, and `N',' + {some column}` will be `null` if `{some column}` is `null`, so this removes the intermediate separators for all omitted values. It *does* kinda presume that `Line1` has a value - without that, there may be a leading comma. You could remove that if needed.

Comment: Well it's not perfect but it's good enough for the purpose I need it for (`Line1` is mandatory if entered through the UI).

Comment: I did wonder whether there was a way to pivot the columns into rows using the `sys.columns` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables - it's probably overkill for my example but I would be interested to see whether it's possible.